# ScalaTest : Exception during running test - java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: scala, scalatest

I am trying to run a test suite written in Scala through commandline and I get following exception.

- Scala version: 2.10.2
- ScalaTest version: 2.10

Following is dependency declared in build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.0" % "test"
```

Following is the stack trace of exception

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps, but interface was expected
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.main(Runner.scala:828)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.main(Runner.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ScalaClassLoader.scala:78)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:24)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:88)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:78)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:101)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.run(ObjectRunner.scala:33)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:40)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:56)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:80)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:89)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```